# Grey Background above UITableView when Large Titles set

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uinavigationbar

I am writing a TableView application that takes the user to a single view when selecting a cell in the table. When I swipe to go back to the TableView, I see this grey area above the TableView that minimizes as the large title appears. How do I change the color of this grey area? I've tried setting the TableView's Header background to another color but that doesn't work. Any advice?

TableView:

[image]

Going back:

[image]

Comment: table style grouped ????

Comment: No TableView style is plain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the fix! To fix this issue set the NavigationBar's isTranslucent property to true

`self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true`